# Что делает функция getWindow().addFlags?

Tags: java, android, камера

Работаю с камерой android и вот есть такая функция

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

в методе

```
onCreate;
```

Что делает эта функция?

Comment: Просит систему держать включенным экран.

Comment: Данная функция не дает девайсу уснуть, пока открыто ваше активити

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) экран устройства будет постоянно включенным (например, это требуется в приложениях для просмотра фильмов или в играх).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
}
```

Преимущество такого подхода в том, что не требуются специальные права доступа и ОС будет корректно отслеживать переключения между приложениями, так что не придется заботиться о самостоятельном освобождении неиспользуемых ресурсов.